# What is the difference between European and American "Ground/Neutral" desgination?

Tags: ac, mains

If 'neutral' is wired to ground back at the electric panel in both continents (or is it?) what is the difference between the two systems?

Neutral is delivered in Europe by the electic company... is it not in the US, and you get get two 120 lives, and you provide your own ground?

Question inspired by this video, which I didn't understand :-)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj5odgJp9fM

Comment: ground and neutral are simply two different things. Anywhere. They exist in both "US speak" and "European speak", and they mean the same things.

Comment: Neutral should be connected to ground at source, mostly transformer or main disconnect. Law ow electricity  and principals are same in all word. Proper name for "ground" is protective earth.

Comment: This has been asked many times over on the [DIY Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) stack, and yes neutral is supplied by the electric company.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/209261/why-bother-referencing-neutral-to-ground-in-residential-transformer

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84423/what-is-the-explicit-difference-between-the-ground-and-neutral-wire-in-110v-syst/84561

Comment: Neutral is supplied by the electric company in the US. It is required to be grounded at the point where the service is connected to the user premises. It may also be grounded near the utility transformer.

Comment: Three phase power means that it is desirable to connect more consumers to the same utility transformer to balance the load better, and that's where the neutral is grounded. With single-phase or split-phase, balance is less of an issue, so there are more and smaller transformers, so you are more likely to have a dedicated transformer with its own grounding point.

Comment: In the US (NEC), protective earth (ground) can be quite a bit more complex for animal sheds and the like. In general, you need to understand what's being achieved and how better to achieve it in each circumstance. Code will help guide.

Answer (score 5):

### Live and Neutral

Both US/Canada and UK systems supply a *neutral*.

The neutral carries the "return" current, and so its conductor size must be of the same gauge as that of the live supply. Neutral and live both run between consumer (e.g. homes) and distribution/generation (your electrical company).

### Single-, split- or three phase

UK residential systems are single phase 230V (live & neutral). This applies to most of Europe.

US/Canada systems are "split-phase" 120V (live-live-neutral) supplying 120V from either live to neutral, or 240V across the two opposite phase lives.

[image]

Consumers using devices requiring high power (commerical ovens, machines, pumps etc..) are often serviced with a three-phase system.

### Protective Earth

In *electric powers systems*, the *Protective Earth* (PE) wiring is generally distinct from the neutral. PE is also known as *Ground* or just *Earth*.

Contrast this with many electronics circuits, where the neutral from the power supply is usually referred to as the ground. We often say that the black or "-" of a DC power supply is connected to the "ground plane" of a PCB.

*Earthing* is a way to make electrical services safe, by helping to protect against electrocution and fires. Earthing is provided differently across the world, mostly due to the prevalence of underground wires (typically in urban areas, much of Europe) vs overhead wires (often in rural areas or suburbs in Canada/US).

Earthing does not require a continuous high-gauge conductor from consumer to distribution.

The earth connection carries currents from the location of a fault (stray voltages, currents or electrostatic discharges) to the nearest earth ("dirt").

Ground wiring is the wire in your cables that is intended to be earthed. It connects to metal casings, piping etc... via the third prong in plugs, but it is not a return wire for the live.

### Grounding, bonding, and earthing

When you connect a metal junction box, a receptacle or a pipe to the ground wiring, it's called **bonding**.

The ground wiring is brought into contact with earth by means of an **electrode** in the form of a grounding **rod** driven 8 to 10ft deep in dirt, a grounding **plate** dug 24in deep in dirt, or, in dryer areas, a grounding rod encased in a concrete slab or other foundation, a.k.a [ufer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ufer_ground).

[image]

In general, keeping ground wiring and neutral wiring separate within a home provides a safe alternative electrical path for stray voltages or currents, which may be due to electrical faults, to be conducted away from people and flammables in order to respectively avoid electrocution or fire.

Earthing the ground further equalizes the home's electrical system so that, for safety, the neutral and ground of the electrical system and all metal pipes (water/gas), roofs etc.. are kept at the same potential as earth ground.

When you touch a pipe, a radiator, or a railing that is earthed at your home, its potential will be equal to the potential of the earth you stand on, and so no dangerous current will flow through your body. Also, no dangerous current will run through or near flammable materials possibly causing a fire.

Thanks to grounding and earthing, any stray voltages, currents and electrostatic charges that are induced or discharged into earthed metal structures of the home will have less chance to come in contact with people and flammables.

Although there are general differences between "American" and "European" *earthing* practices (*voltages* are a different story), you'll find enough regional variations even within the continental split so that no clear line can be drawn: what applies where depends also on historical deployment and geography, not just political borders.

### US and Canada

In most (and perhaps all) areas of US/Canada no dedicated earth conductor is supplied to the home. The neutral is earthed at regular intervals throughout the distribution network (on poles, transformers etc...) and one final time by a grounding rod or plate near the panel in the home.

Due to the prevalence of over-head wiring, this provides a safe earth even if the overhead wires are shorted, for instance if they are downed by a tree. The downed live wire might charge the neutral wire, but it cannot significantly charge the ground system of your house (radiators, plumbing, metal casing of electrical appliances etc...).

> In the **United States** National Electrical Code and Canadian Electrical Code, the feed from the distribution transformer uses a combined neutral and grounding conductor, but *within the structure* separate neutral and protective earth conductors are used (TN-C-S). The neutral must be connected to earth only on the supply side of the customer's disconnecting switch.

[image]

[image]

I added the "bonded at panel" annotation, to show how a fundamentally TT system (e.g. overhead wires) can still effectively be TNC-S, without supplying a dedicated PE to the home.

If the supply is underground, the metal shield of the supply is earthed at the point of distribution and once more at the home. Although an earth bonding is effectively provided this way, it is not relied on for earthing the home's electrical system.

[image]

The green lines are the PE (protective earth) wiring. "BCH" is just an abbreviation for a local Canadian electricity company.

### UK

> TN−C−S
> Part of the system uses a combined PEN conductor, which is *at some point split* up into separate PE and N lines. The combined PEN conductor typically occurs between the substation and the entry point into the building, and earth and neutral are separated in the service head. In the UK, this system is also known as protective multiple earthing (PME), because of the practice of connecting the combined neutral-and-earth conductor via the shortest practicable route to local earth rods at the source and at intervals along the distribution networks to each premises

[image]

[image]

> External earthing: When a new house is built, we install a new power cable which is connected to the wider electricity network. We make sure we provide an earthing terminal to allow your electrician to safely earth the property. There are two types that we will provide. TNS-(Separate earth wire) where an earth is provided off the lead sheath of our electricity cable, or PME (Protective Multiple Earthing) using our neutral cable as a combined neutral earth.

Ref / Images:

- https://www.ukpowernetworks.co.uk/electricity/earthing#Earthinginformation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system
- https://app.bchydro.com/content/dam/BCHydro/customer-portal/documents/distribution/standards/ds-ES43-N2-service-connections-2012.pdf
- https://app.bchydro.com/content/dam/BCHydro/customer-portal/documents/distribution/standards/ds-ES54-S1-01-secondary-single-phase-services-120-240V-up-to-600A.pdf
- https://www.nfpa.org/News-and-Research/Publications-and-media/Blogs-Landing-Page/NFPA-Today/Blog-Posts/2021/05/21/Understanding-Our-Electrical-World-8-Items-that-Form-the-Grounding-Electrode-System
- https://theengineeringmindset.com/ground-neutral-and-hot-wires-us-can/
- https://www.lsp-international.com/power-supply-system/fig-3-tn-c-s-system/